# DOM Jquery não funciona com formulário

Tags: jquery

Tenho esse script que abre uma página html com o **DOM do Jquery**

```
$('.abas').on('click', function(){
   var paginas = ["planejamento_estrategico2.php","mentoria_fast_food.php","terceirizacao.php","marketing_full-time.php","mastermind.php"];
   aba_index = $(this).attr('tabindex');
   $('.abas').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   $("#texto").load ("http://dominio.com.br/"+paginas[parseInt(aba_index) - 1]);
});
```

E esse onde faz uma requisição para um arquivo PHP e mostra o resultado dentro de uma determinada div.

```
$(document).on('click', '#reg-form_3', function(e){

            e.preventDefault(); 

            $.ajax({
                url: 'email_planejamento.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(this).serialize() 
            })
            .done(function(data){
                $('#form-content_2').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('#form-content_2').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                });
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');    
            });
});
```

Meu problema está na hora em se que clica no input do formulário,  já executa o script acima sem clicar no botão submit do form.

Preciso que quando o usuário coloque o email e ao clicar no botão submit do formulario, aí sim, faça a requisição do arquivo php e mostra o resultado na div. Como poderia resolver esse problema com o DOM do jquery?

Meu html

```
<form action="email_planejamento.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" id="reg-form_3" novalidate>
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.2">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f6-p1065-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="1065">
</div>
<div class="digite_email">
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email"><input type="text" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"></span>
</div>
<div class="assinar">
<input type="submit" value="Ver um exemplo de sucesso" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit">
</div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div></form>
```

Comment: O HTML é parte essencial para resolução do seu problema, edite sua pergunta e inclua seu HTML para que possamos analisar  o que está acontecendo.

Comment: desculpe, esqueci do html mesmo, já está lá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está capturando todo clique no elemento com id `reg-form_3` o que ocorre é que esse elemento é o formulário, ou seja, toda vez que clicar no formulário seu script será executado.

Para solucionar mude o **seletor** do método para o `<input type="submit" />`

```
$(document).on('click', '#reg-form_3 input[type="submit"]', function(e){
   ...
});
```

Ou se preferir pode adicionar um id no `<input type="submit" />` e capturar o click nesse elemento:

```
<input type="submit" value="Ver um exemplo de sucesso" 
   id="btnSubmit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit" />

$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function(e){
  ...
});
```

Comment: Não precisa nem colocar um id no botão. Basta alterar o seletor para `'#reg-form_3 input[type="submit"]'`

Comment: Boa! Sua solução é mais simples, vou adicioná-la a resposta.